# network visualization in r

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I have the data like below to be visualized

```
Col1  Col2
o1     i1
o1     i2
o1     i3
o2     i1
i1     i9
i1     i5
```

I wanted the output to be a graph which would show me how each element in "Col1" is related to  each element in "Col2"

For example, 1) o1 --> i1 --> i9
             2) o1 --> i1 --> i5
Is there some kind of network graph in R which I can readily make use of.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried already [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/00Index.html)?

Comment: No, I have not. I will definitely check this out.

Comment: You may also want to check out the packages {diagram} and {qgraph}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this:

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=TRUE, text="
Col1 Col2
o1 i1
o1 i2
o1 i3
o2 i1
i1 i9
i1 i5")
require(igraph)
plot(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df)))
```

[image]